# Динамическое изменение свойств объекта и сериализация VB.NET

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, сериализация, десериализация

**Предыстория:**

Имеется программа, которую разрабатываю и использую в повседневке несколько лет, она написана под .NEW framework 3.5 и перейти на другую более новую версию, пока нет возможности. В ней есть куча настроек, которые хранятся в едином конфиге, собираемом через SOAP сериализацию в XML файл. В который в свою очередь записываются массивы, строки, справочники, хеши и конвертированные в JSON объекты.
В связи с тем что программа постоянно дорабатывается, возникает момент когда нужно добавить в какой то  JSON конфиг объект, новые свойства и после их добавления в программе, файлы проектов перестают конвертироваться при чтении, так как не видят новых свойств в уже сохраненном на диске конфиге.

**Есть мысли о решении, собрал небольшое демо (консольное приложение):**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Text

Module MD

    Private storeObject As DataConfig
    Private loadObject As DataConfig

    Private tmpJson As String

    Sub Main()

        '   Создаем тестовый объект
        storeObject = New DataConfig

        '   Присвоим пару значений
        With storeObject
            .PropertyOne = "значение 1"
            .PropertyTwo = "значение 2"
        End With

        '   Конвертнем в Json
        tmpJson = ToJSON(storeObject)

        '   Пытаемся восстановить объект
        loadObject = ToDataConfig(tmpJson)


    End Sub

    Function ToJSON(ByRef obj As DataConfig) As String

        Dim stream1 As New MemoryStream()
        Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(DataConfig))
        ser.WriteObject(stream1, obj)
        stream1.Position = 0
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(stream1)
        Dim jsonOut As String = sr.ReadToEnd

        Return jsonOut

    End Function

    Function ToDataConfig(ByVal json As String) As DataConfig

        Dim js As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(DataConfig))
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))

        Return js.ReadObject(ms)

    End Function


End Module
```

Код класса `DataConfig`

```
Public Class DataConfig

    Private _property_one As String
    Public Property PropertyOne() As String
        Get
            Return _property_one
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _property_one = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _property_two As String
    Public Property PropertyTwo() As String
        Get
            Return _property_two
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _property_two = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Вопрос:**

Слышал про то, что есть в .NET, динамические объекты, и возможность динамически задавать свойства объекту во время выполнения программы.

1. Как собственно дописать класс `DataConfig` для подобного
   использования?
2. Как использовать в примере, между конвертацией в json и
   восстановлением обратно в объект?

[ссылка на проект, на яндекс диске](https://yadi.sk/d/J3BP42ivm9LEa)

**update**

Ответ на C# не принимается, у вопроса нет метки C#, нужно изменить код приведенный в вопросе.

**update**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**update**

Применил библиотеку `Newtonsoft.Json` при попытке десериализации ошибок не выдает, но и объект не заполняет вложенными свойствами, заполняет только свойства верхнего уровня.
Испытуемый JSON:

```
{
  "ExProperty": {
    "_disabled": false,
    "_el_class": null,
    "_enum_values": [],
    "_id": "124",
    "_inline_script": null,
    "_inline_style": null,
    "_innerHTML": null,
    "_input_max": 0,
    "_input_min": 0,
    "_input_min_zero": false,
    "_input_subtype": null,
    "_nolabel": true,
    "_onclick": null,
    "_order": 0,
    "_parent_wrapp_class": "rrrrrrr",
    "_placeholder": null,
    "_value": null,
    "_width": 0,
    "_wrapp_class": null,
    "_wrapp_col_md": 55,
    "_wrapp_label_class": "eeee",
    "_dt_append": null,
    "_dt_append_name": null,
    "_dt_name": null,
    "_fieldSet": [
      "qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
      "aaaaaaaaaaa",
      "ssssssssssssss",
      "dddddddddddddd",
      "fgfffffffffffffffffff"
    ],
    "_fieldset_name": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "_isfiltr": false,
    "_lbl": null,
    "_lbl_short": null,
    "_lkp_filter": null,
    "_lkp_idas": null,
    "_lkp_nameas": null,
    "_lkp_table": null,
    "_req": false,
    "_sh_in_add": false,
    "_sh_in_edit": false,
    "_sh_in_list": false,
    "_type": null
  },
  "PropertyOne": "значение 1",
  "PropertyThree": null,
  "PropertyTwo": "значение 2"
}
```

Код который пытается выполнить десериализацию.

```
tmpJson = File.ReadAllText("test.json")
loadObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataConfig)(tmpJson)
```

В ходе обратных испытаний, выяснилось что форматы не совпадают, то есть сконвертировав объект методом

```
tmpJson = File.ReadAllText("test.json")
loadObject = ToDataConfig(tmpJson)
tmpJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loadObject)
```

На выходе получим похожий JSON, но в другом порядке.

```
{
  "PropertyOne": "значение 1",
  "PropertyTwo": "значение 2",
  "PropertyThree": null,
  "ExProperty": {
    "fieldSets": [
      "qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
      "aaaaaaaaaaa",
      "ssssssssssssss",
      "dddddddddddddd",
      "fgfffffffffffffffffff"
    ],
    "fieldset_name": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "lbl": null,
    "lbl_short": null,
    "type": 0,
    "req": false,
    "lkp_table": null,
    "lkp_nameas": null,
    "lkp_idas": null,
    "lkp_filter": null,
    "dt_name": null,
    "dt_append_name": null,
    "dt_append": null,
    "sh_in_edit": false,
    "sh_in_add": false,
    "sh_in_list": false,
    "isfiltr": false,
    "order": 0,
    "wrapp_col_md": 55,
    "parent_wrapp_class": "rrrrrrr",
    "wrapp_class": null,
    "wrapp_label_class": "eeee",
    "el_class": null,
    "value": null,
    "innerHTML": null,
    "placeholder": null,
    "nolabel": true,
    "width": 0,
    "onClick": null,
    "inlineStyle": null,
    "Disabled": false,
    "Id": "124",
    "inlineScript": null,
    "inputSubtype": null,
    "InputMinZero": false,
    "inputMin": 0,
    "inputMax": 0,
    "EnumValues": []
  }
}
```

Задача почти решена, но требует доработки все же.

**update**

Добавил [ссылку на проект](https://yadi.sk/d/J3BP42ivm9LEa) с демонстрацией вложенного объекта `ExProperty`

Comment: Какой доработки? Сохранения порядка элементов? JSON не чувствителен к порядку элементов. Если честно, я не понимаю в чем суть вопроса.

Comment: Если проблема в том, что "объект не заполняет вложенными свойствами, заполняет только свойства верхнего уровня" - то стоит привести весь код класса. у вас в DataConfig два строковых свойства - что в нем должно заполняться, но не заполняется? Откуда берется `ExProperty`?

Comment: я вижу то для `Newtonsoft.Json` чувствителен к формату, он сохраняет не приватные а публичные свойства объекта, когда как `DataContractJsonSerializer` сохраняет приватные свойства.

Comment: весь код очень сложен и он в отдельной библиотеке, проблема не в порядке а описана в комменте выше

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь _"сохраняет не приватные а публичные свойства"_ -- Newtonsoft.Json работает с приватными свойствами -- пример [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/5673266).

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь раз уж первоначальная проблема в том, что у вас поле newPropertyValue отмечено как обязательное - может вы хотя бы код объявления этого поля приведете? Вместе с минимальным примером - класса из двух свойств, и json, который можно скопировать и запустить локально.  `<DataMember(IsRequired:=False)>` на этом поле должно было помочь :)

Comment: @PashaPash добавил ссылку на проект на ЯД, классы в библиотеке.  `json` файл в корне.

Comment: @Stack похоже на то что надо, но там код на `C#`, не уверен что так просто его конвертну в `VB`

Comment: на vb.net - [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27447879/5673266)

Comment: @Stack первый ответ по ссылке, как минимум 2008 студия не понимает, класс `MyContractResolver` с кучей ошибок для нее.

Comment: у вас какая версия .NET? в nuget пакете для Newtonsoft.Json есть сборки для .net20 и выше. вам надо выбрать соответствующую.

Comment: @Stack 3.5, вопрос не в сборке либы а в том что в 2008 студии о лямбда выражениях ничего неизвестно в `VB`

Comment: @Stack `        props.ForEach(Sub(p)
                          p.Writable = True
                          p.Readable = True
                      End Sub)` этот код из класса не понимает студия http://clip2net.com/s/3rZ8WX4

Comment: _" в 2008 студии о лямбда выражениях ничего неизвестно в VB"_ --  вместо .Select ниже определяете цикл и для каждого props вызывается CreateProperty и т.д.

Comment: боюсь мне не понятно что там куда и как писать(

Comment: vb.net я не знаю. наверное самое простое - создать отдельный вопрос: как перевести vb.net код c лямбдами в код с циклами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> возникает момент когда нужно добавить в какой то JSON конфиг объект, новые свойства и после их добавления в программе, файлы проектов перестают конвертироваться при чтении

Для десериализации используется `DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(DataConfig))`.

Если в JSON имена меняются, то десериализация работать не будет.
Т.е. надо вносить изменения в DataConfig.

Но проще использовать, например, json.net (с nuget.org скачайте пакет [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.1)).

Пример использования в vb.net - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676708/simple-working-example-of-json-net-in-vb-net).

В json.net есть поддержка запросов похожих на xpath. Т.е. даже если структура JSON меняется, можно находить необходимые объекты по имени или по расположению.
Пример использования SelectToken - [тут](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).

UPDATE:

Как скачать пакет с nuget.org и извлечь из него сборки?
Ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475908/196972)

UPDATE:

В Newtonsoft.Json есть возможность работы с приватными свойствами/полями.
Пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/5673266).

Comment: Так они туда и вносятся в `DataConfig` в программе, а не в файл!

Comment: нету `nuget` в 2008 студии.

Comment: @Дмитрий _"нету nuget в 2008 студии."_ -- пакет можно скачать вручную. добавил update в ответ.

Comment: я знаю про эту библиотеку, попробую

Comment: появились тестовые испытания и новые данные в вопросе. При изменении кода класса, и попытке десериализации сохраненного `JSON` ошибок не происходит и объект заполняется на столько, сколько есть информации в файле, что и требовалось. Но несовместимость форматов все же не позволяет заменить метод сериализации и десериализации.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [использовать](http://json.codeplex.com/) и JObject.

Не пишу на VB и студия не установлена, сразу извиняюсь за ошибки.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Text

Module MD

Private dynamic settings As JObject

Private tmpJson As String

Sub Main()

    tmpJson = string json = @"{CPU: 'Intel', Drives: ['DVD ad/writer', '500 gigabyte hard drive']}"

    '   Загружаем конфиг'
    settings = ToDataConfig(tmpJson)

    '   Присвоим пару значений'
    With settings
        .PropertyOne = "значение 1"
        .PropertyTwo = "значение 2"
    End With

    settings.PropertyThree = "значение 3"

    '   Конвертнем в Json'
    tmpJson = ToJson(settings)

    '   Загружаем конфиг'
    settings = ToDataConfig(tmpJson)
End Sub

Function ToJSON(ByRef obj As JObject) As String

    Dim jsonOut As String = obj.ToString()

    Return jsonOut

End Function

Function ToDataConfig(ByVal json As String) As JObject

    Return JObject.Parse(json)

End Function


End Module
```

[Более подробно](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing)

Comment: требуется готовый код, исходник прикреплен, его надо доработать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь вы ошиблись сайтом, за готовым кодом вам надо к фрилансерам обращаться.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov имеется ввиду что надо доработать пример а не какой то другой код давать. Да и зачем давать нерабочий код? В чем смысл ответа если код из него не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется в данном случае можно словарь обычный использовать. Я к сожалению в VB не силен, так что извините код на C#:

Это модульный тест:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace like.a.dynamic.tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class LikeADynamicTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void LikeADynamic_constructor_test()
        {
            LikeADynamic instance = new LikeADynamic();
            Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(IDictionary<string, object>), instance);
        }

        [Test]
        public void LikeADynamic_usage_test()
        {
            string firstName = "Jack";
            string lastName = "Sparrow";
            DateTime birthDate = new DateTime(1788);

            LikeADynamic pirate = new LikeADynamic();

            pirate.Add("FirstName", firstName);
            pirate.Add("LastName", lastName);
            pirate.Add("BirthDate", birthDate);
            pirate["Gender"] = "Male";

            Assert.AreEqual(4, pirate.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(firstName, pirate["FirstName"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(lastName, pirate["LastName"]);
            Assert.AreEqual(birthDate, pirate["BirthDate"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Male", pirate["Gender"]);
        }

        [Test]
        public void LikeADynamic_ToJson_test()
        {
            LikeADynamic pirate = new LikeADynamic();

            pirate.Add("FirstName", "Jack");
            pirate.Add("LastName", "Sparrow");
            pirate.Add("BirthDate", new DateTime(1788, 1, 1));

            string expected = "{\"FirstName\":\"Jack\",\"LastName\":\"Sparrow\",\"BirthDate\":\"01.01.1788 0:00:00\"}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, pirate.ToJson());

        }
    }
}
```

А это самая элементарная реализация:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace like.a.dynamic
{
    public class LikeADynamic:Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public string ToJson()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");

            for(int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", this.Keys.ElementAt(i), this.Values.ElementAt(i)));

                if (i < this.Count - 1)
                    sb.Append(",");
            }

            sb.Append("}");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Или может быть я вопрос неправильно понял?

**Обновление**
Код на VB. Модульный тест:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()> Public Class LikeADynamicTest

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub LikeADynamic_constructor_test()

        Dim pirate As New LikeADynamic
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(pirate, GetType(IDictionary(Of String, Object)))
    End Sub

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub LikeADynamic_usage_test()
        Dim firstName As String = "Jack"
        Dim lastName As String = "Sparrow"
        Dim birthDate As Date = Date.MinValue

        Dim pirate As New LikeADynamic

        pirate.Add("FirstName", firstName)
        pirate.Add("LastName", lastName)
        pirate.Add("BirthDate", birthDate)

        Assert.AreEqual(3, pirate.Count)
        Assert.AreEqual(firstName, pirate("FirstName"))
        Assert.AreEqual(lastName, pirate("LastName"))
        Assert.AreEqual(birthDate, pirate("BirthDate"))
    End Sub

    <TestMethod()> Public Sub LikeADynamic_ToJson_test()

        Dim pirate As New LikeADynamic

        pirate.Add("FirstName", "Jack")
        pirate.Add("LastName", "Sparrow")
        pirate.Add("BirthDate", New Date(1788, 1, 1))

        Dim expected As String = "{""FirstName"":""Jack"",""LastName"":""Sparrow"",""BirthDate"":""01.01.1788 0:00:00""}"

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, pirate.ToJson())

    End Sub


End Class
```

И реализация:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Public Class LikeADynamic
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Public Function ToJson()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("{")

        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Count - 1
            sb.Append(String.Format("""{0}"":""{1}""", Me.Keys.ElementAt(i), Me.Values.ElementAt(i)))

            If i < Me.Count - 1 Then
                sb.Append(",")
            End If
        Next

        sb.Append("}")
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function

End Class
```

Вопрос был концептуальный, это подразумевалось или что-то другое?

**Обновление**

Добавил в комплект еще один модульный тест, на тему разбора JSON строки:

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub LikeADynamic_ParseJson_success_test()

    Dim data As String = "{""FirstName"":""Jack"",""LastName"":""Sparrow"",""BirthDate"":""01.01.1788 0:00:00""}"

    Dim pirate As LikeADynamic = LikeADynamic.ParseJson(data)

    Assert.AreEqual("Jack", pirate("FirstName"))
    Assert.AreEqual("Sparrow", pirate("LastName"))
    Assert.AreEqual("01.01.1788 0:00:00", pirate("BirthDate"))

End Sub
```

И добавил к реализации класса LikeADynamic простейший механизм разбора:

```
Public Shared Function ParseJson(ByVal data As String)

    Dim result As New LikeADynamic

    Dim dirtyPairs() As String = data.Split(",")

    For i As Integer = 0 To dirtyPairs.Length - 1

        result.Add(ExtractKey(dirtyPairs(i)), ExtractValue(dirtyPairs(i)))

    Next

    Return result

End Function

Private Shared Function ExtractKey(ByVal data As String)
    Dim parts() As String = data.Split(":")
    Return parts(0).Trim({"{"c, "}"c, """"c})
End Function

Private Shared Function ExtractValue(ByVal data As String)
    Dim firstColonIndex As Integer = data.IndexOf(":")
    Return data.Substring(firstColonIndex, data.Length - firstColonIndex).Trim({"{"c, "}"c, """"c, ":"c})
End Function
```

Обновленный проект залил в репозиторий https://bitbucket.org/SergeyEgorov/i.am.so.dynamic

Comment: Вопрос был практический, а не концептуальный.

Comment: А это что за конструкция `<TestMethod()>`? на какой версии данный пример работает?

Comment: Пример работает на версии 3.5. Скачайте его из гитового репозитория и запустите https://bitbucket.org/SergeyEgorov/i.am.so.dynamic Конструкция <TestMethod()> это атрибутивная нотация Visual Basic образца 2008 года https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39967861(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить свойствам атрибут [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) с параметром [`IsRequered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired(v=vs.110).aspx) установленным в `false`.

Comment: `<DataMember(IsRequired:=False)>` не помогло, ошибка что в ответе на скрине так и остается.