# Как перевести `VB.NET` код c лямбда-выражениями в код с циклами

Tags: .net, vb.net, сериализация, json.net

Проект под .NET 3.5 в Visual Studio 2008, это продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473596/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-vb-net) про сериализацию/десериализацию и динамически меняющиеся свойства JSON.

В [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444616/vb-net-serialize-and-deserialize-private-members-simple-example/27447879#27447879) имеется решение вопроса несовместимости форматов сериализаторов, которое состоит в том что по умолчанию `Newtonsoft.Json` сохраняет **публичные свойства** в JSON, а `DataContractJsonSerializer` сохраняет **приватные свойства**. Соответственно сериализация одного и того же объекта дает разный результат.

Для `DataContractJsonSerializer`

```
{
  "ExProperty": {
    "_disabled": false,
    "_el_class": null,
    "_enum_values": [],
    "_id": "124",
    "_inline_script": null,
    "_inline_style": null,
    "_innerHTML": null,
    "_input_max": 0,
    "_input_min": 0,
    "_input_min_zero": false,
    "_input_subtype": null,
    "_nolabel": true,
    "_onclick": null,
    "_order": 0,
    "_parent_wrapp_class": "rrrrrrr",
    "_placeholder": null,
    "_value": null,
    "_width": 0,
    "_wrapp_class": null,
    "_wrapp_col_md": 55,
    "_wrapp_label_class": "eeee",
    "_dt_append": null,
    "_dt_append_name": null,
    "_dt_name": null,
    "_fieldSet": [
      "qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
      "aaaaaaaaaaa",
      "ssssssssssssss",
      "dddddddddddddd",
      "fgfffffffffffffffffff"
    ],
    "_fieldset_name": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "_isfiltr": false,
    "_lbl": null,
    "_lbl_short": null,
    "_lkp_filter": null,
    "_lkp_idas": null,
    "_lkp_nameas": null,
    "_lkp_table": null,
    "_req": false,
    "_sh_in_add": false,
    "_sh_in_edit": false,
    "_sh_in_list": false,
    "_type": null
  },
  "PropertyOne": "значение 1",
  "PropertyThree": null,
  "PropertyTwo": "значение 2"
}
```

Для `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
{
  "PropertyOne": "значение 1",
  "PropertyTwo": "значение 2",
  "PropertyThree": null,
  "ExProperty": {
    "fieldSets": [
      "qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
      "aaaaaaaaaaa",
      "ssssssssssssss",
      "dddddddddddddd",
      "fgfffffffffffffffffff"
    ],
    "fieldset_name": "aaaaaaaaaaa",
    "lbl": null,
    "lbl_short": null,
    "type": 0,
    "req": false,
    "lkp_table": null,
    "lkp_nameas": null,
    "lkp_idas": null,
    "lkp_filter": null,
    "dt_name": null,
    "dt_append_name": null,
    "dt_append": null,
    "sh_in_edit": false,
    "sh_in_add": false,
    "sh_in_list": false,
    "isfiltr": false,
    "order": 0,
    "wrapp_col_md": 55,
    "parent_wrapp_class": "rrrrrrr",
    "wrapp_class": null,
    "wrapp_label_class": "eeee",
    "el_class": null,
    "value": null,
    "innerHTML": null,
    "placeholder": null,
    "nolabel": true,
    "width": 0,
    "onClick": null,
    "inlineStyle": null,
    "Disabled": false,
    "Id": "124",
    "inlineScript": null,
    "inputSubtype": null,
    "InputMinZero": false,
    "inputMin": 0,
    "inputMax": 0,
    "EnumValues": []
  }
}
```

Требуется переписать класс из ответа, так чтобы он компилировался в 2008 студии.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Public Class MyContractResolver
    Inherits DefaultContractResolver
    Protected Overrides Function CreateProperties(type As Type, memberSerialization As MemberSerialization) As IList(Of JsonProperty)
        Dim props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).
                            Select(Function(p) MyBase.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization)).
                            Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).
                            Select(Function(f) MyBase.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization))).ToList()

        props.ForEach(Sub(p)
                          p.Writable = True
                          p.Readable = True
                      End Sub)
        Return props
    End Function
End Class
```

Сейчас код не воспринимается, ибо нет таких конструкций в 2008 версии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код лучше поставить в начало вопроса, т.к. тот кто знает vb.net cразу его увидит и сможет переписать без лямбд -- для этого читать описание проекта не обязательно. я предлагал [правку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/50370).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант, должно сработать:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Public Class MyContractResolver
    Inherits DefaultContractResolver
    Protected Overrides Function CreateProperties(ByVal type As Type, ByVal memberSerialization As MemberSerialization) As IList(Of JsonProperty)
        Dim props As New List(Of JsonProperty)()

        Dim propsInfo As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)

        For Each pi As PropertyInfo In propsInfo
            Dim jp = MyBase.CreateProperty(pi, memberSerialization)
            If Not props.Contains(jp) Then
                props.Add(jp)
            End If
        Next

        Dim fieldsInfo As FieldInfo() = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)

        For Each pi As FieldInfo In fieldsInfo
            Dim jp = MyBase.CreateProperty(pi, memberSerialization)
            If Not props.Contains(jp) Then
                props.Add(jp)
            End If
        Next

        For Each p As JsonProperty In props
            p.Writable = True
            p.Readable = True
        Next

        Return props
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, VB2008 ещё не понимал многострочные лямбды, поэтому соответствующую функцию можно сделать обычной, либо просто сделать обход списка циклом:

```
For Each p In props
  p.Writable = True
  p.Readable = True
Next p
```

Comment: За что минус-то?

Comment: за банальный копипаст, после того как правильный полный развернутый ответ уже был дан.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, во-первых, я не смотрел, что в том ответе. И это не копипаст хотя бы потому, что я вот сейчас их сравниваю, и там тип указан, а у меня - нет, там имени переменной в Next нет, а у меня есть. Во-вторых, на твоём скриншоте только последний блок не компилируется - я вот не понимаю, зачем же надо вместо этого одного куска переписывать всю программу? Переписать огромный лишний кусок - называется "полным развёрнутым ответом"?

Comment: Если почитать пост с которого все началось, то станет понятно что код требовалось переписать, чтобы он стал понятен мне, мне нужен был развернутый код чтобы в него можно было нормально условия еще вставить. У вопроса, заголовок "Как перевести `VB.NET` код c лямбда-выражениями в код с циклами"

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, в тексте вопроса сказано: "Требуется переписать класс из ответа, так чтобы он компилировался в 2008 студии." То что заголовок шире, чем текст вопроса - это не повод утверждать, что я неправильно понял вопрос. Я поменял кусок, достаточный для того, чтобы код скомпилировался. На мой взгляд, это логично и вопросу соответствует.

Comment: Отредактируйте свой ответ, я сниму минус и закроем тему, ок?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, ok.